# how to perform div hover shows another div but both div's are different form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

i have created two forms, one form having the div that div id is "one" second form having the another div id is "two".When div one hover the div two wants to be displayed. i have tried like this.

```
<form action="">
<div id="one">
<p>source of hover content</p>
</div>
</form>
<form action="">
<div id="two">
<p>destination of hover content</p>
</div>
</form>
```

In Css:

```
#two{ 
    display: none;
}
#one:hover #two {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: @danny3b is it possible to do in jquery, both are different forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clr;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(function() {
        $("#one,#two").bind('mouseout', function(){
            clr = setTimeout( function(){$("#two").css("display", "none");} , 2000);
        })
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#one,#two").bind('mouseover', function(){
            clearTimeout(clr);
            $("#two").css("display", "block");          
        })
    });
});
```

```js
var clr;
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(function() {
  $("#one,#two").bind('mouseout', function(){
   clr = setTimeout( function(){$("#two").css("display", "none");} , 500);
  })
 });
 $(function() {
  $("#one,#two").bind('mouseover', function(){
   clearTimeout(clr);
   $("#two").css("display", "block");   
  })
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<form action="">
<div id="one" style="border: 1px solid #000; width:200px;padding:5px;">
<p>source of hover content</p>
</div>
</form>
<form action="">
<div id="two" style="border: 1px solid #000; width:200px;padding:5px;display:none;">
<p>destination of hover content</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

To `show/hide` second `div` on hover of first `div` use below script.

```
$(function(){
  $("#one,#two").hover(function(){
    $("#two").show();
  },function(){
    $("#two").hide();
  });        
});
```

Please check working demo:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#one,#two").hover(function(){
    $("#two").show();
  },function(){
    $("#two").hide();
  });        
});
```

```css
#two{ 
  display: none;
}
#one:hover #two {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="one">
    <p>source of hover content</p>
  </div>
</form>
<form action="">
  <div id="two">
    <p>destination of hover content</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks its working. but my second content is not visible.when i put alert its taking content only not visible

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to each of your forms
Then, you can use jQuery to point a specific element within a form

```
<form id="form1" action="">
  <div id="one">
    <p>source of hover content</p>
  </div>
</form>
<form id="form2" action="">
  <div id="two">
    <p>destination of hover content</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Using jQuery you can specify each element inside a particular form

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form2 #two").hide();
  $("#form1 #one").hover(function(){
  $("#form2 #two").show();
  });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JavaScript and supported in all browsers** using `Element.style.display` and `Element.onmouseover` & `Element.onmouseout` for hover events

```js
String.prototype.Tshow = function(s){
document.getElementById(this).style.display = s ? "block" : "none";
}


document.getElementById("one").onmouseover = function(){"two".Tshow(true)}

//to hide onmouseout
/*
document.getElementById("one").onmouseout = function(){"two".Tshow(false)}
*/
```

```css
#two{ 
    display: none;
}
#one:hover{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
<div id="one">
<p>source of hover content</p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="">
<div id="two">
<p>destination of hover content</p>
</div>
</form>
```